# Using imread in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I have installed EmoPy  in google collab,

```
pip install EmoPy
```

and tried to execute the following code.

showing error in imread command.Please help me out

```
from EmoPy.src.fermodel import FERModel
from pkg_resources import resource_filename


target_emotions = ['calm', 'anger', 'happiness']
model = FERModel(target_emotions, verbose=True)

print('Predicting on happy image...')
model.predict(resource_filename('EmoPy.examples','image_data/sample_happy_image.png'))

print('Predicting on disgust image...')
model.predict(resource_filename('EmoPy.examples','image_data/sample_disgust_image.png'))

print('Predicting on anger image...')
model.predict(resource_filename('EmoPy.examples','image_data/sample_anger_image2.png'))

AttributeError: module 'scipy.misc' has no attribute 'imread'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or alternatively, you can use imread from OpenCV2, cv2.imread

Answer (score 1):

`imread` is deprecated in SciPy 1.0.0, and will be removed in 1.2.0. I think you are using version 1.2 or later. There are two ways to solve this:

1. Uninstall your scipy and install version 1.1.0 using the following commands

```
pip uninstall scipy 
pip install scipy==1.1.0
```

2. Instead of using `imread` from scipy use it from `imageio` (`imageio.imread` instead of `scipy.misc.imread`) as mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.2.1/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imread.html). But of course you need to import `imageio` into your environment

I would recommend the first option since I don't see you explicitly using `scipy.misc.imread` in your code, so you have to change it internally where ever it is being called. The first solution is quite neat and clean, where you just downgrade the version and it's all done.